# Why can't I connect to my localhost port from a remote computer?

Tags: ssh, firewall, ip, ufw, port-forwarding

I'm using link-grammar server to convert sentences into semantic graphs. It provides an API though a port to do the above process. It's configured to works through port `9000` of `localhost`. I used to connect it through the `telnet` client with the following command.

```
telnet localhost 9000
```

I need to connect it from a remote computer. I am using a server at [pythoanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) . I want to connect to my local host form the bash terminal of pythonanywhere.com. So I tried `telnet <my ip> 9000`. It didn't work. It says 
`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`.

I found my ip adress by searching on google.
It was `61.245.173.164`

I also found my ip adress by ifconfig command. `ifconfig |grep inet`. It was `10.225.149.159`

Why are they different? Which one should I use?

Should I disable any firewall. I tried `sudo ufw disable`. No result still. Hope anyone can help me. :-) Thanks.

Comment: you should check hostname -I (uppercase) for braodcast ip adderss. localhost points to nowhere. it's just your local computer. to access remote address, try ssh than telnet for security reason. if you are using university's network, access address in a university from outside usually is not possible because there is a network gate (61.245.173.164) hosting all the traffic. so you cannot see your address inside that gate,

Comment: and connections usually are filtered. (inside the network topology your address is 10.225.149.159).